# Infini loop on a script using rsync

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made a function using rsync copying file from rep1 to rep2. I used getopt to create an argument calling this function. The function is called in the case but doing an infinite loop, i don't know why. I tried this function without case and it worked nicely.

Stuff in rsync():

```
    read -p 'Enter source directory : ' repSource
    read -p 'Enter destination directory : ' repDest


    if [ -e $repSource ] && [ -d $repSource ] && [ -e $repDest ] && [ -d $repDest ]
    then
            echo "File exists and it is a directory !"
            echo "Synchronisation of " $repSource "to " $repDest
            rsync -av $repSource  $repDest


    else

            echo "File doesn't exit or it is not a directory  !"
    fi
```

Here my case:

```
OPTS=$(getopt -o h,m,p,a,l,t) 
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi

    case "$1" in

             -h) aide;
               exit 0;;
             -m) RAM;
               exit 0;;
             -p) CPU;
               exit 0;;
             -a) logcpu;
               exit 0;;
             -l) autolog;
               exit 0;;
             -t) rsync;
               exit 0;;
    esac
```

Here the result:

```
Enter source directory : rep1/
Enter destination directory : rep2/
File exists and it is a directory !
Synchronisation of  rep1/ to  rep2/
Enter source directory :
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did anyone tell you that naming shell functions as real commands is a Very Bad Idea? Shell is a hard language to use, I won't recommend it for newbies.

Comment: The use of `-e` is redundant; the `-d` test will fail if the argument doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing the "real" command `rsync` with your function of the same name. You can keep `rsync` as the function name, but then you need to use the built-in `command` to ignore the function and call the real command.

```
command rsync -av "$repSource" "$repDest"
```